# Which rational slopes have angle bisectors with rational slopes?

Tags: geometry, rational-numbers, slope

This question was inspired
by the following question
in quora:

The lines
$y = 1/3 x$
and
$y = 13/9 x$
are drawn in the coordinate plane.
What is the slope of the line that bisects the angle these lines make?

It turns out that
the slope of the bisector
is 3/4 (and, of course,
-4/3).

This suggested the question:

Which rational slopes
have angle bisectors
with rational slopes?

There are a number of related questions,
but I have not seen this
particular variation.

Here's what I have so far.

If the slopes are
$a$ and $b$,
by using
$\tan(u-v) = (\tan(u)-\tan(v))/(1+\tan(u)\tan(v))
$,
we can show that
the slope $x$ of the bisector
satisfies
$x^2+2rx-1 = 0
$
where
$r = (1-ab)/(a+b)
$.

From this,
$x
=-r \pm \sqrt{1+r^2}
$.

For this to be rational,
$\sqrt{1+r^2}
$
must be rational.

It turns out that
$1+r^2
=\dfrac{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}{(a+b)^2}
$
so a necessary and sufficient condition
is that
$(1+a^2)(1+b^2)$
is a rational square.

If
$a = \dfrac{s}{t}, b=\dfrac{u}{v}$,
this is equivalent to
$(s^2+t^2)(u^2+v^2)
$
beinga square,
or,
using the standard identity,
$(su\pm tv)^2+(sv\mp tu)^2
$
is a square.

What I do not know
is
necessary and sufficiaent
conditions on
$s, t, u, v$
which make
$(s^2+t^2)(u^2+v^2)
=(su\pm tv)^2+(sv\mp tu)^2
$
a square.

In the original problen,
$a = 1/3, b = 13/9$,
so
$s^2+t^2 = 10,
u^2+v^2 = 250
$
and
$(su\pm tv)^2+(sv\mp tu)^2
=(13\pm27)^2+(9\mp 39)^2
=40^2+30^2
=50^2$
or
$14^2+48^2
=4(7^2+24^2)
=4(25^2)
=(50)^2
$.

I haven't been able
to take this
any further.

The tags could use improving,
too.

Comment: Reduce to the case $a=0$, so $u^2+v^2$ is a square, which is of course the classification of primitive pythagorean triples $u=A^2-B^2, v=2AB$ or the other way depending on which one is even.